# 0 returns undefined in Live code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple code,

```
var movieRecordID = $scope.moviesCheck.filter(function(x){
    return x.movie_id == $scope.movieListID.id;
});
$scope.lolMOvie = movieRecordID[0].id
```

This returns a object and stores it into a variable called `movieRecordID`. To get to the ID value inside the object I have to use `[0]`.

Locally this works fine, but live it throws an error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Any ideas why?

Comment: Try to see what `movieRecordID` is after you attempt to define it.

Comment: Try to check if `movieRecordID` is really an object, if it's an array you'll just have to access it `movieRecordID[0]['id']`.

Comment: @choz `movieRecordID` isn't a object, but an array. Sorry for that confusion. But for some reason I can't use `[0]` on the array.

Comment: Alright, I have found the problem. After I create my record, I request the movie data again. But it doesn't show the newly created record. Just the old ones. That's why `[0]` isn't working. Since it doesn't find anything. Why this is different on live and locally is a riddle though.